# iOS Passbook Automatic Update Notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, passbook, wallet

I am having problem displaying the update notification message when I update my pass on the device. Pass is being updated, just the notification is not being shown. I understand that I need to place `changeMessage` key in the pass with the information which is updated in the pass.

I wanted to ask how the `pass.json` will look with `changeMessage` if the only thing I updated was the locations (latitude, longitude values). Should I just add `changeMessage` key in every location dictionary along with latitude and longitude key ? (I tried that and pass went invalid)

Comment: ChangeMessage keys not valid for location dictionaries.  It is not possible to trigger a lock screen message when only updating locations.

Comment: @PassKit is it possible to update the locations together with other fields and by that trigger the lock screen notification?

Comment: Yes - you can change anything in the pass.json except for the PassTypeIdentifier and SerialNumber.

Comment: Ok so from what I understood from your answer on this and another question, that you can only display update notification if you update Lower-Level Pass Structure Dictionary Keys (as apple likes to call em) ? Can you confirm this please.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.